# Why was std::hash not defined for std::weak_ptr in C++0x?

Tags: c++11, hash, weak-ptr, stdhash

After reading the discussion on operator< for std::weak_ptr, I can't see any reason why defining std::hash to use the control block for std::weak_ptr wouldn't work. I also can't believe that this was ignored by the standards committee. Has anybody read the relevant discussion on the topic?

Edit: Discussion on operator< for std::weak_ptr 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1590.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am somewhat familiar with the history.  There's another later paper you should also read:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2637.pdf

And I believe this later paper is what is actually in the current draft.  In summary, shared_ptr has value-based operator<() *and* ownership-based member functions owner_before.  weak_ptr has only the latter.

My best guess is that hash-support for weak_ptr simply got dropped.  No one proposed hash support for weak_ptr to the best of my knowledge.  There have been many, many issues in bringing C++0x to standardization, a limited amount of time and resources to work the issues, and no doubt there will be mistakes and missing pieces.

I also think to add hash support for weak_ptr it would have to be done analogously to owner_before:  Add the member function owner_hash to both shared_ptr and weak_ptr.  I suspect it is too late to do this for C++0x, but this seems like a plausible TR2 proposal.

Comment: It turns out that Japan actually reported this.

Comment: So ... those of us who need to hash a weak pointer, and are too lazy to figure it out ... what code should we write?

Comment: I see no way to write this function as a client as described above with `owner_hash`.  Clients simply don't have access to the field that needs to be hashed.  This can only be provided by the std::lib implementor.  I do not know how a client could write a non-error-prone hash function for `weak_ptr`.  Maybe someone else has a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Japan complained about this (see [lwg issue 1406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-index.html#1406)), and that exactly what Howard suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775849/294313) was proposed as the resolution.  Unfortunately, it was postponed (presumably because of time constraints).