# Is calling map::count with an empty weak_ptr as argument safe?

Tags: c++, dictionary, initialization, find, weak-ptr

Is it safe to call [`map::count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) on an [uninitialized thus empty `weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr) safe?

I'm still very inexperienced with c++ and do not have the skills to determine this.

In my application, a `weak_ptr` is being held as key in a `map` and must be found first by the values.  If it cannot be found, an uninitialized `weak_ptr` is `return`ed and used in `map::count`.

### Code

Setup

```
map<my_ptr, connection_data, owner_less<my_ptr>> m_connections;
typedef map<my_ptr, connection_data, owner_less<my_ptr>>::iterator it;
```

Find by data

```
my_ptr get_my_ptr_from_data(string data){
    my_ptr my_ptr_to_send;
    for(it iterator = my_ptrs.begin(); iterator != my_ptrs.end(); iterator++) {
        if(iterator->second.data == data){
            my_ptr_to_send = iterator->first;
            break;
        }
    }
    return my_ptr_to_send;
}
```

Finding

```
my_ptr found_ptr = get_my_ptr_from_data(data);
if(my_ptrs.count(found_ptr) ){
```

Comment: Does `std::weak_ptr` even define comparison semantics? I dont think so

Comment: Could you demonstrate a bit more of your actual code? I have the feeling you're asking about a XY-problem.

Comment: @Gracchus: It works as expected - until one of the elements expires, and breaks the ordering of the map. Then you've got undefined behaviour, since you've broken one of the map's preconditions. You can't safely use `weak_ptr` as a key.

Comment: Essentially the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22110715/15416)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe to call `find` (and `count`), as long as whatever ordering you've defined doesn't rely on the pointer being non-empty. The only thing that `find` (and `count`) will do with the argument is use it as an argument for the comparator.

However, it's not safe to use `weak_ptr` as a key in an associative container. If it expires, then the container's order is broken, and trying to use the container afterwards will give undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Gracchus: No problem, the answer's the same for `count`, since that does more or less the same thing as `find`.

Comment: @Gracchus: It's either wrong (if there's any chance that the pointers could expire) or unnecessary (since, if they can't expire, you might as well store shared pointers, or even raw pointers).

Comment: If they cannot expire, storing shared_pointer's instead of raw pointers might add unneccessary overhead as would weak_pointer's for sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think shared pointers would have the same overhead as weak, but would remove any danger of expiry. Raw pointers would have less, and a different flavour of undefined behaviour if they did expire.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: On many implementations `sizeof(std::shared_pointer) == 2 * sizeof(T*)`, because fast access to the pointer is optimized over space consumption. (Somewhere it must save its shared counters). `std::weak_pointer` cannot do that optimization, because it must always ensure the object still exists, so it must access the counters anyway.

Comment: @Gracchus: That's a bug any way you see it.

Comment: One point that I think should be clarified:  A `set` of weak_ptr is safe as long as you are using owner_less, since that relies on the underlying control object.  That control object will not be deleted until all of the weak_ptr's are also destroyed.