# How to implement a boost::unordered_map with websocketpp::connection_hdl as key?

Tags: c++, key, unordered-map, weak-ptr, websocket++

For my application, it is much more convenient and logical to hold a map of [`websocketpp::connection_hdl`](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/websocketpp/common/connection_hdl.hpp)s as keys in a map, but I've found that this could be potentially dangerous since they are `weak_ptr`s.

However, it's been [claimed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110715/1382306) that a `boost::unordered_map` may not break if a `weak_ptr` key expires.

Is that true?  If so, how can one be constructed to hold `connection_hdl`s as keys as well as be inserted, erased, and found/counted?  Also, what is necessary to be able to loop through them, such as with a `for`?

This is currently beyond my skillset, so I'm unsure of what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::unordered_map` could be slow on iteration, thus, I would suggest that you could store all `websocketpp::connection_hdl` in a `std::vector`. For the map you can use pointers as keys: `boost::unordered_map<websocketpp::connection_hdl*, X>`

Comment: Yes. Or if O(log(n)) time on iteration and lookup is okay for you, use a std::map.

Comment: All stl containers are what you put in stays there. You have to remove expired connections out of every container yourself.

Comment: Thank you again!  Does this answer and your comments conflict with this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23156251/1382306  This is all well beyond my skills, and I need to get this right.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The pointer will always point to some address, order or hash is always defined. Just take care of removing the entries of expired connections.