# Smart pointers for set of abstract objects?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm relatively new to programming and recently, while I was doing the assignment I came across a problem that I'm not sure how to cope with. I have an abstract class called `IPrintable` and it represents printable objects. Class `UnorderedSet` is an unordered set of `IPrintable` objects, it is actually a dynamically allocated array of pointers to the `IPrintable` objects. The problem is that this implementation bounds lifetime of objects that exist somewhere in memory and "elements" in my set. I'm aware that when those objects get destructed my pointers will point to the deallocated memory block. Can someone tell me how to manage it? The only idea that I can think of is to use a dynamically allocated array of shared smart pointers, but I'm not sure how to do that.
Maybe something like this?

`std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<ns1::IPrintable>> set`;
But how to get shared_ptr from the array? Can I use `set[index]`?

```
    class UnorderedSet:virtual public IPrintable
        {
            int* n;
            int* i;
            IPrintable** set;
    public:
    UnorderedSet(int n):n(new int(n)),i(new int(0)),set(new IPrintable*[n])
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            set[j] = nullptr;  // I cant have set[j]= new IPrintable 
                                  because its abstract class
    }
    ...
    void insert(IPrintable* const iprt)
    {
        if (*i == *n)
            this->add_capacity();// extends capacity
        set[*i] = iprt;
        (*i)++;
    }
    ...
    }
class IComparable:public IPrintable
    {
        virtual double compare_criteria()const = 0;
    public:
        virtual ~IComparable()=default;
        std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const IComparable&)const;
    };
class Complex: public IComparable
    {
        double *re, *im;
    public:
...}
int main()
{
Complex* z=new Complex(1,1);
UnorderedSet uset(4);
uset.insert(z);
z->~Complex();// uset.set[0] points to the deallocated memory block
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a concrete example? Including the problem it causes. In general, you should try to have a clear owner of those objects, using `shared_ptr` as a lazy solution is not a good idea. Use it only when there are truly multiple owners.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a container that holds a smartpointer type just like you would with any other type e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IPrintable>> myvec;
```

And then you would be able to access it by array indexing:

```
myvec[0];
```

A `shared_ptr` uses reference counting to know when it should be deleted as the deleter will be called when it reaches `0` references.

A `unique_ptr` is used to represent an item which you want only `1` reference to.

You have to take certain care with `unique_ptr` in containers as a `unique_ptr` is non-copyable.

E.g. you could create the pointer within the vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IPrintable>> myvec;
myvec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<IPrintable>());
```

And ensure you access the elements by reference rather than taking a copy e.g.:

```
for(auto& printable : myvec) {
    //use printable unique_ptr
}
```

Also:

```
z->~Complex();// uset.set[0] points to the deallocated memory block
```

You shouldn't be manually calling the destructor but rather call `delete` on `z`. If you want your `UnorderedSet` to take ownership of the allocated memory, you can have your `UnorderedSet` call `delete` on it's items in the `UnorderedSet`'s destructor or when an item is removed from the set.

Comment: I just dont want elements,that my pointesr point to, to get out of the scope and get destructed before my UnorderedSet object gets destructed.

Comment: @gprincip Then delete them only when you are done with them. Or yes you could use smart_pointers which will much more reliable in terms of ensuring resources get released appropriately. Calling `delete` on the `z` pointer will call the destructor and that can be done inside your `UnorderedSet`.

Comment: "*You have to take certain care with unique_ptr in containers as a unique_ptr is non-copyable.*" I would say `smart_ptr`s require even more care, because one may want to  deep-copy a vector and default copying will cause an additional reference/ownership instead. While in case of `unique_ptr`s the compiler will clearly manifest it with an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to not insist on an unordered set of `IPrintable` then the
example below might give some guidance. The `z` element lives only for a short
period and is automatically destroy but still detected by the `std::weak_ptr`
when iterating over the container.

I deliberately avoid using `std::make_shared` in this example since a
control block created by `std::make_shared` will also hold the allocation area
for the object in question. If the `weak_ptr` lives a lot longer than the
original `shared_ptr` then that memory will not be reclaimed until the last
`weak_ptr` is destroyed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class IPrintable
{
public:
   virtual ~IPrintable() = default;
   virtual void print()  = 0;
};

class Real : public IPrintable
{
   int re{};
public:
   Real(int) {}
   void print() override { std::cout << "Real::print()\n"; }
};

class Complex : public IPrintable
{
   double *re{}, *im{};
public:
   Complex(double, double = double{}) {}
   void print() override { std::cout << "Complex::print()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::weak_ptr<IPrintable>> printables;
   std::shared_ptr<Real> r(new Real(3));
   {
      std::shared_ptr<Complex> z(new Complex(4, 5));
      printables.push_back(z);
   }
   printables.push_back(r);
   for(auto& wp : printables)
      if(auto sp = wp.lock())
         sp->print();
      else
         std::cout << "Lost entry\n";
}
```

This example should print:

```
Lost entry
Real::print()
```

Comment: Why not make it an `unordered_set` of weak pointers?

Comment: @einpoklum, difficult without more tangable data on what `IPrintable` really holds. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695640/how-to-make-a-c11-stdunordered-set-of-stdweak-ptr

Comment: Oh, you mean because of the lack of a hash? But can't you just hash the address, in OP's case?

Comment: Not only do you need a `hash` but also defined `operator==` for them too. Anyway, if you have two or more `weak_ptr`'s to the same object the address of each `weak_ptr` will be different. The real problem is that the *key* in the `unordered_set` is supposed to be **constant** and the *value* of  a `weak_ptr` can change thus rendering it not suitable for a key value in an `unordered_set`.